# Show a div on desktop and show another div on mobile with CSS

Tags: css, show-hide

I want to show a particular div on desktop and tablet but I wanna hide this div in the mobile screen. In the mobile screen I wanna show another div, so I want to swap the two divs.

This is my attempt:

```
.div-only-mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 849px) {

.div-no-mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.div-only-mobile {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}

}
```

Comment: Just use `@media all` and set also `display: none` to div-no-mobile and you should be set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes using `media query` you can `hide div` at certain `screen-resolution` as in below example, but `CSS` styling property `visibility` just `hides` an `element`, but still `layout` is visible that effects other elements, to hide it totally use `display` as `none`, try below example,

```css
.desk{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}
.div-only-mobile{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:orange;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 1920px){
  .div-only-mobile{
  visibility:hidden;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width : 906px){
 .desk{
  visibility:hidden;
  }
 .div-only-mobile{
  visibility:visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desk">Large Screen</div>
<div class="div-only-mobile">Only Mobile</div>
<p>Demo Text.</p>
```

Comment: Just using visibility will make the div take up space even though it's not visible.

Comment: @thepio that's true it's just hides element not it's layout, as in above codes it affects the layout and p tag is aligned at bottom, whereas if display:none totally hides a div from layout. Was just adding the difference between them.

Answer (score 7):

```
.div-only-mobile {
    display: none;
}
.div-no-mobile {
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 849px) {

.div-no-mobile {
    display:none
}

.div-only-mobile {
    display: block;
}

}
```