# Can media query really handle a mobile device

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an `<input type="number">` and I need the up and down spinner buttons for choosing the next value. Unfortunately, those spinner buttons are not visible on a mobile device. So, I want to create up and down buttons and display them only on mobile devices. The only [thing I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199148/show-a-div-on-desktop-and-show-another-div-on-mobile-with-css), is a media query that displays a DOM element, when the screen size is small. But what, if the user simply decreases the browser window on a PC for some reason? This would display the spinner buttons as well as my up and down buttons.
Next thing I tested was

```
@media-desktop (min-width: 1px) {
  .desk {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .div-only-mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

but both divs are visible on PC and mobile device.

How can I display a DOM element on a mobile device and hide it on PC?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://modernizr.com/

Comment: No, media queries can _not_ actually detect that a device is a "mobile device." You can try and detect a combination of factors that might enable an "educated guess" at best, like f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62793120/1427878

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work

```
.desk {
 visibility: visible;
}


.div-only-mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .desk {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .div-only-mobile {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is almost the same, like the link I posted. It does not work, because it checks the screen size and not if it is PC or mobile device. What if the screen size on a PC is reduced to the screen size of a mobile device?

Comment: If you want to definitively work out of a user is on a mobile device or not you'll need to use JavaScript

Comment: It's a Blazor wasm so I prefer C# but I will find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/javascript-interop/how-do-you-detect-whether-a-page-is-loaded-in-mobile-or-on-desktop) is a simple solution for Blazor, that uses js.